# EGARCH fitting in R

Tags: programming, garch

I am using the `fGarch` package in R to analyze stock volatility. To do this I am using the `garchFit` formula on my time series. The general form of `garchFit` is:

```
garchFit(formula = ~ garch(1, 1), data = dem2gbp,
init.rec = c("mci", "uev"),
delta = 2, skew = 1, shape = 4,
cond.dist = c("norm", "snorm", "ged", "sged", "std", "sstd",
"snig", "QMLE")
```

I was wondering if there is a way to adapt the formula so that I can fit an `EGARCH(1, 1)`. Currently I am only able to change the lag lengths `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible with just `fGarch` but is with the [`ruGarch`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/index.html) package. See this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41723575/862288) for a discussion and more information.